# Auth Controller not Exist in laravel 5.7 with JWT Authentication

Tags: jwt, laravel-5.7

I am trying to implement JWT authentication with laravel 5.7 but i am facing an issue while sending a request in Laravel. the error is as follows.

```
error: Object { message: "Class App\\Http\\Controllers\\App\\Http\\Controllers\\AuthController does not exist", exception: "ReflectionException", file: "C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\laravel+angular\\backend\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Container\\Container.php", … }
​
headers: Object { normalizedNames: Map(0), lazyUpdate: null, lazyInit: lazyInit()
 }
​
message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:8000/api/login: 500 Internal Server Error"
​
name: "HttpErrorResponse"
​
ok: false
​
status: 500
​
statusText: "Internal Server Error"
​
url: "http://localhost:8000/api/login"
```

here is my auth controller

```
   <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class AuthController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new AuthController instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:api', ['except' => ['login']]);
    }

    /**
     * Get a JWT token via given credentials.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

        if ($token = $this->guard()->attempt($credentials)) {
            return $this->respondWithToken($token);
        }

        return response()->json(['error' => 'Unauthorized'], 401);
    }

    /**
     * Get the authenticated User
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function me()
    {
        return response()->json($this->guard()->user());
    }

    /**
     * Log the user out (Invalidate the token)
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function logout()
    {
        $this->guard()->logout();

        return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
    }

    /**
     * Refresh a token.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    public function refresh()
    {
        return $this->respondWithToken($this->guard()->refresh());
    }

    /**
     * Get the token array structure.
     *
     * @param  string $token
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
     */
    protected function respondWithToken($token)
    {
        return response()->json([
            'access_token' => $token,
            'token_type' => 'bearer',
            'expires_in' => $this->guard()->factory()->getTTL() * 60,
            'user'=> auth()->user()->name
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Get the guard to be used during authentication.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard
     */
    public function guard()
    {
        return Auth::guard();
    }
}
```

it says AuthController does not exist where as i checked and i have it in my http->controller folder in laravel project. please help me ! Thanks ..!!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a namespace issue:

`App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController`

Notice how `App\Http\Controllers` is repeated?

It looks like you might have forgotten a leading `\`, perhaps using `App\Http\Controllers\AuthController` instead of `\App\Http\Controllers\AuthController` somewhere. Without it, the namespace is *relative* to the current namespace of whatever script it was used in. It's similar to relative or absolute paths in files and urls.

If it happened while defining an authentication route, by default Laravel will prepend the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace to whatever controller name you gave as the action (you can see this defined in RouteServiceProvider.php).

**Edit:**

The problem seems to be caused by outdated instructions in the [guide](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/) that you followed:

> First let's add some routes in `routes/api.php` as follows:
>
> ```
> Route::group([
>
>     'middleware' => 'api',
>     'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',
>     'prefix' => 'auth'
>
> ], function ($router) {
>
>     Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
>     Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
>     Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
>     Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
>
> });
> ```

Routes defined in `routes/api.php` *already* have a namespace of `App\Http\Controllers`, so the namespace given to this `Route::group()` is being *appended* to that namespace, causing the duplication I mentioned above. **If you delete the `'namespace' => 'App\Http\Controllers',` line you should solve this specific error.**

You can see in their [develop branch](https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/develop/quick-start/) that the line has already been removed from the guide:

> First let's add some routes in `routes/api.php` as follows:
>
> ```
> Route::group([
>
>     'middleware' => 'api',
>     'prefix' => 'auth'
>
> ], function ($router) {
>
>     Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
>     Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
>     Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
>     Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');
>
> });
> ```

Comment: i have edited my question please let me know where is the mistake. thanks..!! i have followed the documentation for using jwt authentication in laravel..from https://jwt-auth.readthedocs.io/en/docs/quick-start/ here

Comment: @PranaySute can you include your routes file?

Comment: @PranaySute nevermind, I don't think I'll need to see the routes. I think you can fix it by removing `use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;` from the controller. You're already in that namespace, so I think that's causing the problem. If that works I'll update my answer

Comment: it is still saying the same error. on the documentation itself it is given like this ..!

Comment: @PranaySute I've updated my answer, please let me know if that solves the problem